# How to change the scale of the y axis in excel

Tags: excel

I have a large amount of graphs that represent a bunch of survey questions.  Some questions have different scales (1=Never, 2=Sometimes, 3=Often, 4=Very often, others are from 1 to 7).  The data I did was to find the average for each year (we have been doing this for 10 years) and make a longitudinal analysis for it.  However, I can't recall how to change the scale from the basic 1, 2, 3, 4 to the actual text scale of Never, Sometimes, Often, Very Often.  I tried looking up some guides but none of it really got me the results.  I guess the simple way would be how can I get the text even on the upper and lower bounds if its not simple to get the inner regions (2 and 3) on the table.  Also, this is in excel just for a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

1- Rgith-Click on your your chart and select menu item `Select Data...`

2- In the dialog that appears, on the right side you have a box named *"Horizontal Category Axis Labels"*. Click `Edit`

3- In the dialog that appears, named *"Axis Labels"*, type `Never, Sometimes, Often, Very Often` (or copy this sequence from somewhere and paste it there).

Comment: This is useful when it comes to changing the X axis but I am trying to change the y axis scale.  It is current showing values 1.9 through 2.6 on intervals of .1, and I want to be able to change the scale display to be from 1 to 4 but to show the text of which each means.  I can get the scale to show 1 to 4 easily, its just the text changing part I am having issues with.